# is it possible to play AppleMusics inside my app? If yes then how can i play this?

Tags: swift, avplayer, apple-music, apple-musickit

I'm beginner to iOS development. I want to play AppleMusic inside my app. please let me know is it possible or not?

If it is possible then please suggest me how can i play this.

I found this [Link](https://medium.com/combo-fm/navigating-the-apple-music-ios-api-e9dd2c3ea65a) but i don't know wether it play music with iPhone default player or AVPlayer?

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with music kit. Check out https://developer.apple.com/musickit/, but the users will need to have an apple music account.